# Adding text to a Bing Maps Polygon via js

Tags: bing-api, bing-maps

I am trying to solve a problem using Bing maps v7 JS API.  My problem is that I need a custom callout or bubble with the beak pointing to a specific position (lat/lon) and the bubble portion containing 2-4 short lines of text which describe that point.  The bubble portion should be movable (and the text within it).

Our first try at this was using a pushpin and an infobox.  This functioned as desired but was not aesthetically pleasing.  It was created where the pushpin could be moved and the infobox followed.   The only option to mark the original location of the pushpin once it was moved was to extend a polyline from the pushpin tip to the original point.  This really wasn't intuitive when looking at the map because the actual location was not at the push pin but at the end of the polyline connecting the pushpin to the original location.  Also, there were 3 different objects used for each point which detracted from the presentation of the map.

Now, alternatively, I have created a polygon resembling a callout whose bubble portion can be moved around while keeping the beak pointing to the desired location (this is a requirement as well).  What I can't figure out is how to place text within the polygon.  Moving this text with the polygon would be the next hurdle but something that I am pretty sure that I can handle once I figure out how to place it.  The text needs to be, say white, with a transparent background so that it appears it and the polygon are one.

In this application there will be 3-8 of these callouts.  And each may have their bubbles re-positioned so that they may all fit in the screen view.

How can I place text within a polygon using the v7 JS API?

Thanks!

Any ideas

Comment: Is there a reason why this can't be implemented with a Pushpin and a polygon?  The Pushpin can have a background image resembling the bubble, and you can assign your text to the pushpin.  Implement the callout with a polygon triangle.  The tip will be at your specific position, while the opposite side can be at the location your pushpin.  Make your pushpin draggable, and when the pushpin is dragged you update your polygon.  There will be some vector math involved in drawing the polygon triangle's side at the pushpin location.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!  That is the route we ended up going.  We are now addressing resizing the polygon portion through zoom levels to make it match the bubble.  I couldn't figure out how to get text inside a polygon though I am sure there is a way.  Thanks again for your reply.